# NextJS: what is the proper way to handle dynamic route pages?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I'm working on a project in NextJS for the first time, and I'm wondering what the right way to handle dynamic routing is.

I have a `http://localhost:3000/trips` route which displays a page with list of cards, each of which represent a "trip":

[image]

When I tap on one of these cards, I want to navigate to a dynamic page for that route such as `http://localhost:3000/trips/0b68a50a-8377-4720-94b4-fabdabc12da1`

This is my folder structure:

[image]

As you can see, I already have the dynamic routes set up and it is working.

TripCard is the card component. TripComponent is a grid of TripCards. trips/index.tsx contains the TripsComponent (and other UI).

Currently I'm handling the dynamic route in TripCard as:

```
import { Trip } from './Models'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const TripCard = ({ trip }: { trip: Trip }) => {
    const router = useRouter()
    return (
        <div className="card bg-base-100 shadow-xl hover:bg-gray-100 active:bg-gray-300">
            <div className="card-body" onClick={() => router.push('/trips/' + trip.id)}>
                <h2 className="card-title">{trip.name}</h2>
                <p>This is a trip!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TripCard
```

And the dynamic page [tripId].tsx looks like:

```
import { NextPage } from 'next'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const TripPage: NextPage = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const tripId = router.query.tripId
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is {tripId}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TripPage
```

And TripsComponent.tsx:

```
import { Trip } from './Models'
import TripCard from './TripCard'

const TripsComponent = ({ trips }: { trips: Trip[] }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
                {trips.map((trip: Trip) => (
                    <div>
                        <TripCard trip={trip}></TripCard>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TripsComponent
```

And trips/index.tsx:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { GetStaticProps, InferGetStaticPropsType, NextPage } from 'next'
import { Trip } from '../../components/Models'
import TripsComponent from '../../components/TripsComponent'

const TripsPage: NextPage = (props: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
    return (
        <div className="m-9">
            <h1 className="mt-9 text-3xl font-bold text-slate-800">Your Trips</h1>
            <div className="justify-end">
                <button className="btn btn-primary">Add Trip</button>
            </div>
            <div className="divider"></div>
            <TripsComponent trips={props.data} />
        </div>
    )
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    // fetches data and passes to props
}

export default TripsPage
```

I guess my question is, what is the proper way to do routing like this where I have cards, and each card will go to a dynamic URL with an associated page? In TripCard I have a hardcoded router.push:

`<div className="card-body" onClick={() => router.push('/trips/' + trip.id)}>`

But that doesn't seem like the right way to handle this. For example, what if I want to use TripCard in another view and go to another route?

What's the best way to structure code that performs this function in NextJS?

Comment: i have this [link](https://stackblitz.com/github/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/dynamic-routing?file=pages%2Fpost%2F[id]%2Findex.js) from next.js's github that i think might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to pass the url as props and use NextJs [`<Link/>`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link):

```
import { Trip } from './Models'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Link from 'next/link'

const TripCard = ({ trip, url }: { trip: Trip, url: string }) => {
    const router = useRouter()
    return (
        <div className="card bg-base-100 shadow-xl hover:bg-gray-100 active:bg-gray-300">
       <Link href={url} passHref>
            <div className="card-body">
                <h2 className="card-title">{trip.name}</h2>
                <p>This is a trip!</p>
            </div>
        </Link>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TripCard
```

And then use the component like this:

```
<TripCard trip={trip} href={'/trips/' + trip.id}></TripCard>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This seems like the best way to do it. I can also pass in the baseUrl in index as `<TripsComponent trips={props.data} baseUrl="/trips/" />` and then do my TripCard as `<TripCard trip={trip} url={baseUrl + trip.id}></TripCard>`

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic routes, you will have to use **getStaticPaths** and **getStaticProps** to fetch the paths before and generate all the paths. When you export getStaticPaths from the page Nextjs will pre-render all the paths specified by **getStaticPaths**.

**getStaicPaths** has to return two things paths and fallback. paths property will have to be an array of params. And fallback means should Nextjs look for pages and pre-render if not pre-rendered before. Suppose after publishing the site you created a new card. So, If the fallback is true NextJs will look for the card in the database and pre-render then store it in the file system. If fallback is false it will show 404 not found.

Also Instead of using router.push use Link component.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths

Answer (score 0):

The routing you have implemented is correct only. Maybe you can try like this

For trips, you can navigate to `/trips` and for each trip `/trip/<trip id>`

If you want to make the trip URL dynamic then you can pass the URL itself to TripCard component.

`url` will be `<route name>/<trip id>`

`<TripCard trip={trip} url={url}></TripCard>`